# Remove italics (# comments) in Rmarkdown code chunks in pdf

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, chunks, italic

I am looking to find a way to remove the italicized comments in Rmarkdown code chunks

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
    number_section: no
---

```{r}
# This is a test.
```
````

And the results.

[image]

Is there a way to make it not italicized?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several code highlight styles do not italicize the comments, including `haddock`, `kate`, and `zenburn`.  See [here](https://www.garrickadenbuie.com/blog/pandoc-syntax-highlighting-examples/) for a preview of available styles.

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
    number_section: no
    highlight: kate
---
```

If you need to create a custom syntax highlighting theme, instructions in the pandoc manual are [here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#syntax-highlighting).